# Why won't this program work with the OS redirection command in C?

Tags: c, console, text-files, io-redirection

I am working with command prompt features with a simple program to generate a text file in C. Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[80];

    fgets(buf, 30, stdin);
    printf("the input was %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

My programming book is wanting to show how to play with the command prompt to make text files from programs, and instructs typing the word 'redirect' followed by '>' then the name of the program name with '.txt'. as below:

```
redirect> programname.txt
```

Now this IS generating a file 'programname.txt' on the desktop, but it is empty. The book purports that recipe should allow me to enter a string (as the program is DESIGNED to do) and that this string will be inside a generated programname.txt file. Also, there is a warning in the command line: "not recognized as an internal or external command". I've had this schpill before, but the text file generation did WORK, in that it did generate the .txt file. What am I missing here, for this program to work as intended?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't running your program. I highly doubt `redirect` is on your path. Try `./redirect > programname.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused by the fact that it is not your program, but the shell which creates the file `programname.txt`, *before* it even *tries* to run your program.

And after the first succeeded and created an empty file, the latter probably fails because there is no command `redirect` in your PATH or such a thing exists as a builtin in your shell, as has already been suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to perform output redirection in a shell is to use the `> filename`, but not with `redirect` before it contrary to what you say. The thing that comes before the `>` is the command to be redirected.

So, let's say you compile your program and save it as `foo` in the current directory (e.g. `cc -o foo myprogram.c`). In that case, you can redirect its output by saying:

```
./foo > filename.txt
```